# Print string without single quotes & brackets

Tags: python

After installing countryinfo and import CountryInfo, I have tried to print

```
currency = country.currencies()
print(currency)
```

and the result is `['CAD']`. I am interested in `CAD` without quotes & brackets.

Comment: `currency` must be a list with one item. So you'll have to print `currency[0]`.

Comment: I’d recommend searching for (and taking) a Python data structures 101 tutorial on the web.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like `country.currencies()` returns a list, which is why you see `['CAD']`. In order to access the first (and only) element in the list, which is a string, you can use `currency[0]`. To print it, you can use `print(currency[0])`, which will give the desired output.

I would strongly suggest reading about lists, what you can put inside of them, and most importantly, how you can access elements in them.

Comment: It does return a list of strings, like you said - it's shown in the official documentation: https://pypi.org/project/countryinfo/#currencies This is an example of why reading the documentation is so important if you run into an issue. The fact that OP did not read it beforehand means they didn't do their [due diligence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6273251) before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get element of the list by doing this:

```
print(currency[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `countryinfo` [documentation](https://github.com/porimol/countryinfo#currencies), the `.countries()` function returns an array of strings:

```py
# coding=utf-8
from countryinfo import CountryInfo


country = CountryInfo('Singapore')
country.currencies()
# returns array of strings, currencies
# ['SGD']
```

You just need to print a specific entry from an array, in your case it would be:
`print(currency[0])`.